# Can you receive SMS messages in your app on iPhones?

Tags: iphone, sms

I am wondering if you can officially receive SMS messages in your app (and remove the default SMS app). I believe it can be done on Android, I just wonder if this is possible on iPhone OS.

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot. There is no access to an SMS framework from within your application.